# Make webserver on vps only accessable to vpn member

Tags: firewall, vpn, webserver

I've set up a openvpn server (Port 1194) on my vps that has also a webserver (Port 80 and 443) on it. How can I isolate the webserver from the internet so that only members of my vpn can access it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried making the httpd listen only on the VPN IP address?   or blocking access to non-VPN source addresses with iptables rules?

Comment: Binding the webserver to the VPN IP did the trick.

Comment: cool. please write an answer describing what you did.  you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Binding the webserver to the IP of the VPN interface like so: 
`server.bind = "10.8.0.1"` inside `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` is working for me.